# Best method for firing and refiring AJAX via php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

I'm trying to transcribe what my programmer told me. He and I may be doing this all wrong, so I need to make sure he and I am doing it in the right manner. Here is what we are trying to do:

I have a page on a website and within that page, I have a button. When you click on it, I want it to (via AJAX so the page doesn't refresh)

- Send data (time capture) to the DB
- See that the DB recorded the change and in turn return a different value back to the site
- This would in turn change the button, noting that it is in a recording mode.

Think of it in this way, the button is a timer. On click, it records the time in the DB, and in the DB it also changes the state to recording. Since it is in the recording phase, somehow it gets sent back to the website page and changes the button showing that it is recording. Naturally clicking again would stop it and record the time in the DB.

Here is how the snippets are set up (not working I think) ATM:
*sidenote: This is in Joomla

**Page:**

```
<script src="js/ajax_link.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="ajaxlink" onclick="loadurl('php/ticket_timer.php',<?php echo $row->id?>)">Start Time</div>
```

**ajax_link.js**

```
function loadurl(dest,ticket_id) {
jQuery.ajax({
      url: dest,
      type: "POST",
      data: "ticket_id="+ticket_id,
      success: function(msg){
         alert(msg);
         jQuery('#ajaxlink').text("Timer Stop");
      }
   });
}
```

**ticket_timer.php**

```
    <?php
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
    define( 'JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] );

    require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
    require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
    require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );
    $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

    $ticket_id = $_POST['ticket_id'];
     $user =& JFactory::getUser();
     $user_id=$user->get('id');

    //DB Query
$db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'ticket_id', 'user_id', 'times','current_time')));
    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__support_ticket_times'));
    $query->where($db->quoteName('ticket_id') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote($ticket_id));
    $query->where('ticket_id = '. $ticket_id, 'AND')
           ->where('user_id=' . $user_id );
    $db->setQuery($query);

    // Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
    $current_time=$results[0]->current_time;
    $times=$results[0]->times;
    $id_results = $db->loadColumn();
    $db->setQuery($idquery);


    $timesString = $times . ',' . date('Y-m-d g:i');
    echo($timesString);

    if(empty($results[0])){

        $values = array(max($id_results)+1, $ticket_id, $user_id, $db->quote(date('Y-m-d g:i')),$db->quote(date('Y-m-d g:i')));
        //echo "YOU GET NOTHING, MAKING NEW ROW";
        $columns = array('id', 'ticket_id', 'user_id', 'times','current_time');

        // Prepare the insert query.
        $insert_query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $insert_query
            ->insert($db->quoteName('#__support_ticket_times'))
            ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
            ->values(implode(',', $values));

        // Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.
        $db->setQuery($insert_query);
        $db->query();


    }else{
        //echo("CURRENT TIME" . $current_time);
        if($current_time=='0000-00-00 00:00:00'){
            echo "NO TIME";
            $fields = array(
                            $db->quoteName('current_time'). '=' . $db->quote(date('Y-m-d g:i'))
                        );
        }
        // . $db->quote(date('Y-m-d g:i'))
        else{

            echo "ADD TIME";
            $fields = array($db->quoteName('times') . '='  . $db->quote($timesString) ,
                            $db->quoteName('current_time'). "='0000-00-00 00:00:00'"
                        );
        }
        $update_query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $conditions = array(
            $db->quoteName('user_id') . '=' . $db->quote($user_id), 
            $db->quoteName('ticket_id') . '=' . $db->quote($ticket_id)
        );

        $update_query->update($db->quoteName('#__support_ticket_times'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);
        $db->setQuery($update_query);
        $db->query();
     //echo $update_query;
    }

    ?>
```

Can anyone suggest how to get the timer to fire back that the timer has started? Are we butchering this and is there a better way to code this?

Comment: concept makes sense but not sure what you mean at end about `timer to fire back it started`. Assume button click is 2 way...start/stop. More usage details would help. Also, will buttons be repeated on a  page ie multiple tickets?

Comment: Your Javascript should keep track of whether the timer is started or not. Your current Javascript function will always call the same `loadurl` function no matter what the state. Maybe your PHP should return some JSON to tell the Javascript what the state is.

Comment: Charlietfl, button is 2 way, so I'm all ears for a better way to implement. Buttons will not be repeated, just on there once.   HeikkU, are you suggesting that within the ticket_timer.php it should use JSON to tell ajax_link.js its state, and then that would get passed back to the page?

Comment: @hdwebpros Exactly. See my answer for a technique to achieve this.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is. Does you link not change to "Timer Stop" with the current code? Is alert(msg) not showing you whatever your php page echoes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exchange some data between the PHP and the HTML page. The HTML page can be modified with Javascript, of course. The notation typically used for this kind of an exchange is [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json). In this example, we're using JSON to:

1. Send a boolean `timerRunning` to the PHP,
2. change the value in PHP,
3. send a reply,
4. modify the HTML page, and
5. store the `timerRunning` value in the HTML element.

So, for starters, we pass some data from the HTML element to Javascript using the HTML5 `data-` attributes, like this:

```
<div id="ajaxlink" data-url="php/ticket_timer.php" data-ticketId="<?php echo $row->id; ?> " data-timerRunning="false">Start Time</div>
```

In your Javascript, we access the parameters set above and send them to your PHP script via AJAX:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Add an 'onClick' handler to the element
    jQuery('#ajaxlink').on('click', function(event) {
        // Get the url and ticket_id from the element's 'data-' attributes
        var url = jQuery(this).data( 'url' );  
        var data = {
            'ticketId' : jQuery(this).data( 'ticketId' ),
            'timerRunning' : jQuery(this).data( 'timerRunning' )
        }
        // Send an AJAX request
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data
        }).done( function(response) {
            // This runs when the AJAX request succeeds
            if ( 'undefined' == typeof( response.timerRunning ) ) {
                alert( 'The server didn\'t tell the timer state' );
                return;
            }
            // Store the value in the element
            jQuery('#ajaxlink').data( 'timerRunning', response.timerRunning ); 
            // Change the element HTML
            if ( response.timerRunning )
                jQuery('#ajaxlink').html( 'Stop Timer' );
            else
                jQuery('#ajaxlink').html( 'Start Timer' );
        }).fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            // This runs when the AJAX request fails
            alert( 'The AJAX request failed with the error ' + errorThrown );
        });
    });
});
```

In your PHP script, check the `timerRunning` value and react accordingly:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['timerRunning'] ) ) { // Check that we got some value for 'timerRunning'
    if ( $_POST['timerRunning'] ) { 
        // The 'timerRunning' value is TRUE, the timer is running, now stop it
        your_code_here_to_stop_the_timer();
        $reply = array( 'timerRunning' => false );
    } else {
        // The 'timerRunning' value is FALSE, the timer isn't running, now start it
        your_code_here_to_start_the_timer_and_whatever();
        $reply = array( 'timerRunning' => true );
    }
    // Send the correct header for a JSON response
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    // Send the $reply array encoded as JSON
    echo json_encode( $reply );
}
```